# Gradle : Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:1.0.0

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I am using gradle to compile my Groovy and Java code. today I update my groovy 2.5.4 and upgrade gradle to version 5.

`gradle run` command failing now with this error message.

> ```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'.
>    > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:1.0.0.
>      Searched in the following locations:
>        - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.0.0/groovy-1.0.0.pom
>        - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.0.0/groovy-1.0.0.jar
>        - http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.0.0/groovy-1.0.0.pom
>        - http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.0.0/groovy-1.0.0.jar
>      Required by:
>          project :
>
> * Try:
> ```

Here is the **build.gradle** file.

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
      maven {
        url "http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Use the latest Groovy version for building this library
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.4'
    compile group: 'commons-cli', name: 'commons-cli', version: '1.4'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'com.mashape.unirest', name: 'unirest-java', version: '1.4.9'
    compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.6.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.directory', name: 'groovyldap', version: '0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic
    compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.directory.shared/shared-ldif
    compile group: 'org.apache.directory.shared', name: 'shared-ldif', version: '0.9.19'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.directory.api/api-ldap-model
    compile group: 'org.apache.directory.api', name: 'api-ldap-model', version: '1.0.0-M15'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv
    compile group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '4.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup
    compile group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.11.2'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.11'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc
    compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '6.4.0.jre8'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds
    compile group: 'net.sourceforge.jtds', name: 'jtds', version: '1.3.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.6'
 // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml
    compile group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '1.21'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rubiconproject.oss/jchronic
    compile group: 'com.rubiconproject.oss', name: 'jchronic', version: '0.2.8'

    compile group: 'io.github.http-builder-ng', name: 'http-builder-ng-core', version: '1.0.3'

    // Use the awesome Spock testing and specification framework
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.2-groovy-2.5'
}

// Define the main class for the application
mainClassName = 'ssl.test.App'
```

any help to resolve this error message?

Thanks
SR

Comment: Did you check `gradle dependecies` to find out where is `rg.codehaus.groovy:groovy:1.0.0.` ?

Comment: ran this command, but no output `gradle dependencies | egrep 'groovy.*1.0.0'`

Comment: I think you were just a bit too restrictive in your egrep expression:

`    +--- org.apache.directory:groovyldap:0.1-SNAPSHOT`
`    |    \--- groovy:groovy:1.0`

Perhaps you want something like:

`    compile(group: 'org.apache.directory', name: 'groovyldap', version: '0.1-SNAPSHOT') {`
`        exclude(group: 'groovy', module: 'groovy')`
`    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your `groovyldap` dependency declaration with the following (as already mentioned by @paul-king in the comments):

```
    compile(group: 'org.apache.directory', name: 'groovyldap', version: '0.1-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude group: 'groovy', module: 'groovy'
    }
```

This will at least help you get rid of the dependency resolution error.

I don’t know if your `groovyldap` dependency will still work with Groovy 2.5.4 but it’s definitely worth a try.